# My JAR File Won,t Run On Other PCs

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

So I just compiled my application in Netbeans. It works fine if I copy the JAR to my desktop and doubleclick (A small GUI is displayed). But when I run the JAR on another PC, it won't work. Both PCs are running the latest JRE.
The Error Code I get is:"A Java Exception has occured"

I have also tried ziping up the dist folder where the JAR is in, but this did't make sense to me as only the JAR file was inside the dist folder. The third method I tried was zipping up the whole project folder, copying it to the other PC and running the JAR from inside the (unzipped) folder.

The Manifest file reads:
   `Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.2
    Created-By: 1.8.0_11-b12 (Oracle Corporation)
    Class-Path: lib/javaee-api-7.0.jar lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar
    X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
    Main-Class: gui.gui`

Comment: What exception has occured?

Comment: could be some x32 bit or x64 bit issues? are both machines have same architecture?

Comment: Both machines are 64bit

Comment: Try running the JAR from the command line, not by a double click. Then you should be able to see the exception.

Comment: Error: unable to access jarfile WortArtikel.jar

Comment: I'm gonna put my money on missing dependencies.

Comment: Could you please explain to me what these dependencies are and how to ad them? It would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using JDK 8. I simply bootstrapped JDK 7 and everything worked fine.